# Why does seeing the up- and downvote count as a privilege?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, privileges

Why can't all users see upvote and downvote counts? Is it somehow problematic for new users to have this information? The total score doesn't show all of the relevant information (+5-4 and +1-0 are very different, but both total +1), and it would be nice to have this on sites where I don't have enough reputation yet, but I don't see any reason a user who's new to the entire network shouldn't see it either.

Is this just to give people an incentive to participate more and gain rep (seems pointless considering the other privileges, which do have obvious reasons for needing restrictions), or is there some reason I'm missing?

Comment: Are they rhetorical questions (not a rhetorical question)? Is this a feature request to change the existing functionality?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I would have suggested to make it available to all users if there didn't seem to be a reason, but it looks like the goal is to reduce the number of people doing it to reduce server load.